# How can we see the predictable labels in RapidMiner?

Tags: rapidminer

I would like to know how can we see the predictable labels given by a classifier using RapidMiner?

Can we have it as an attribute output as in the clustering results?

Thanks in advance!
Telma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having built a model, use the Apply Model operator to apply it to an example set. The result will have a new attribute with a name like Prediction("labelname") where "labelname" is the name of the label attribute. If the label has polynominal values, additional attributes will be created for each possible value giving the confidence for the prediction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I'm doing cross validation, so the "apply model" operator is inside the testing part of the validation which is connected with the performance operator. I've put a breaking point in the "apply model" operator and I was able to see the prediction labels of subsets of instances. but isn't it possible to have this information at the end with the entire set of instances?

Comment: It is possible to save the subsets into the repository using the Store operator or into memory using the Remember operator. Outside the loop, these can be recovered using Retrieve or Recall. You would have to have a macro that was incremented within the cross validation and use that as part of the name of the subset otherwise you would overwrite the early ones with the later. I would use the repository since that is more permanent if you need to examine the results manually later on.